# How do you switch off the Image Count in NyroModal (lightbox) when displaying images

Tags: javascript, jquery, nyromodal

When using NyroModal to display images it automatically shows the image count of how many are in the collection in the H1 tag when the popup occurs i.e. "1/3", "2/3", "3/3"

Does anyone know how to siwtch this off or manipulate the h1 tag?

I'm also interested in NyroModal automatically positioning the h1 tag at the bottom of the image instead of the default (top).

Plugin is located here: http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the 'Page 1 of ...' in NyroModal, use this javascript:

```
$.nyroModalSettings({ galleryCounts: '' });
```

To place the nyroModal title/heading below the image then go into the nyromodal javascript code (unpacked) and search for the code below and replace 'modal.contentWrapper.prepend' with 'modal.contentWrapper.append'.

```
function setTitle() {
    var title = $('h1#nyroModalTitle', modal.contentWrapper);
    if (title.length)
        title.text(currentSettings.title);
    else
        //modal.contentWrapper.prepend('<h1 id="nyroModalTitle">'+currentSettings.title+'</h1>');
        modal.contentWrapper.append('<h1 id="nyroModalTitle">'+currentSettings.title+'</h1>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the h1 with CSS

```
h1#nyroModalTitle{display:none}
```

Looks like there's also a parameter you can pass through: title: null

Alternatively, you should be able to position the h1 tag at teh bottom, but it might involve editing the source javascript.

Comment: And actually , I see now you're just looking to remove the 1/4 portion. There are two additional params:

galleryLinks:
galleryCounts: